# Create custom module for render custom forms through a controller in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

I need to render a custom form which is created using Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase and Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface through a controller in custom Drupal 8 module. Is there any guidence or reference to follow to do this?

Actually I tried to render form directly and through a controller. But both ways are not working. Only render the submit button. I refer the drupal 8 documentation also. But I couldn't find a solution for this. Please be kind enough to find my coding samples below. If there are anything wrong. Please correct me.

my_module.routing.yml

```
partner.content:
    path: '/partner'
    defaults:
        _controller: '\Drupal\partner\Controller\PartnerController::add'
        _title: 'Add Partner'
    requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'

partner.addform:
    path: '/partner/add'
    defaults:
        _form: '\Drupal\partner\Form\AddForm'
        _title: 'Add Partner'
    requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

AddForm.php

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class AddForm extends FormBase
{
    /**
     * Returns form id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormId(): string
    {
        return 'my_module_add_form';
    }

    /**
     * Build form array
     *
     * @param array $form
     * @param FormStateInterface $formState
     * @return array
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array
    {
        // First name
        $form['first_name'] = [
            '#type'     => 'textField',
            '#title'    => t('First Name'),
            '#required' => true,
        ];

        // Other input fields...

        $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Save Changes'),
            '#button_type' => 'primary',
        );

        return $form;
    }

    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}
}
```

MyModuleController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\my_module\Form\AddForm;

class MyModuleController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function add()
    {
        $addForm = new AddForm();
        $form    = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($addForm);

        return [
            '#theme' => 'form_my_module_add',
            '#form'  => $form,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Hemantha Dhanushka, before answering your question, I would need some guidance. Drupal is able to render Form directly from the router (`your_module.routing.yml`) - Why do you want to render the Form from the Controller ? Do you want an answer about rendering a Form via a route (it's the most common case - and best pratice - to render Page with a Form) or you really want to render the Form from the Controller point-of-view ?

Comment: @KevinWenger I tried that way also. But when I do it, it only rendered the submit button. Not other fields. I edited my question above. Please check my code and if anything wrong, help me to correct it. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you to use the first approach (using routing instead of Controller). Also, it seems: you use the wrong `#type` for your `first_name`. Try `textfield` instead of `textField`.

If you need more help, I would post here an answer with an full example.

Comment: @KevinWenger I'm really appreciate your help. If you can give me a full example it would be great.

Comment: @KevinWenger Problem solved :). You were correct. Problem was in `textField`. Thanks mate for the help.

Comment: Happy to help. I copy/past the comment into a proper answer to clarify this question has an answer, feel free to mark it as the correct answer so people will know it has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to find out the solution with Hemantha Dhanushka on my comment.

To make it clear this question has a correct answer, here I past the validated comment.

> I would recommend you to use the first approach (using **routing::_form** instead
>   of **Controller**). Also, it seems you use the wrong `#type` for your
>   `first_name` field. Try `textfield` instead of `textField`.

---

Also, for people who want to go further, here are some links to implement a proper 
**routing::_form** approach to expose a form as a page instead of using a Controller: https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/step-by-step-method-to-create-a-custom-form-in-drupal-8.

For people looking for more help about existing Form Element Reference (`textfield`, `checkboxes`, `entity_autocomplete`, ...) here is an excellent up-to-date article https://drupalize.me/tutorial/form-element-reference?p=2766

Answer (score 0):

You can use `buildForm()` method for it. Check below code example:

```
public function add()
{
    $form_state = new Drupal\Core\Form\FormState();
    $form_state->setRebuild();
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->buildForm('Drupal\my_module\Form\AddForm', $form_state);

    return [
        '#theme' => 'form_my_module_add',
        '#form'  => $form,
    ];
}
```

Reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder::getForm/8.2.x